# Вопрос по заданию на С++ по библиотеке STL

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Вот задание: Дан массив из N целых чисел. Найти среднее арифметическое элементов массива, кратных числу k. Поменять знак у всех элементов массива между первым максимальным и последним максимальным элементами. Если первый отрицательный элемент имеет четный индекс, то поменять местами части
массива относительно этого элемента. Удалить из массива нулевые элементы. Отсортировать первую половину массива по возрастанию.

Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace std;

int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int N, k;
    cout << "Введите количество элементов" << endl;
cin >> N;
    vector <int> v(N);   

    cout << "Введите элементы" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)  
    {
        cin >> v[i];                    
    }

    cout << "Значения второго вектора " << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl<< "какому числу должно быть кратное? k= " << endl;
    cin >> k;
    double sum = 0;
    int kol = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <N; i++)
    {
        if (v[i]%k == 0) {
            sum += v[i];
            kol += 1;
        }
    }

    cout << sum / kol << endl;

    cout << "Максимум " << *max_element(v.begin(), v.end()) << endl;
    cout << "Mинимум: " << *min_element(v.begin(), v.end()) << endl;

    _getch();
return 0;
}
```

Остановился на 3 предложении. Собственно вопросы: 1) *min_element(v.begin(), v.end()) - обязательно использует разыменование? Смотрел примеры - не везде используется. 2) Как подступиться к 3 заданию (предложению)? Правильно я понял, что, например, в copy нельзя запихнуть цикл, а только методы?; 3) Если бы я использовал диапазон, где первый элемент указала минимальный, а последний максимальный, то работал бы он, если они не в том бы порядке расположены были? К примеру, в copy указано с мин до макс, а на деле макс будет раньше минимального.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> `*min_element(v.begin(), v.end())` - обязательно использует разыменование?

`min_element` возвращает итератор. Разыменовывание нужно, если вы хотите получить значение, лежащее по этому итератору. Если вам нужен сам итератор, то оно, очевидно, не нужно.

> "Если первый отрицательный элемент имеет четный индекс, то поменять местами части массива относительно этого элемента."
>
> Как подступиться к 3 заданию (предложению)? Правильно я понял, что, например, в copy нельзя запихнуть цикл, а только методы?

Не понимаю вопрос. Во-первых, `std::copy` сам проходит с помощью цикла по всем элементам диапазона. Зачем еще один (видимо вложенный) цикл? Во-вторых, что мешает поместить цикл в функцию, которую вы передаете в `std::copy`?

Я бы создал еще один вектор, скопировал в него две половинки массива через `std::copy(..., std::back_inserter(new_vector))`, и заменил старый вектор на новый. Это проще всего.

> 3) Если бы я использовал диапазон, где первый элемент указала минимальный, а последний максимальный, то работал бы он, если они не в том бы порядке расположены были? К примеру, в copy указано с мин до макс, а на деле макс будет раньше минимального.

Это бы не сработало. Стандартные функции, принимающие пару итераторов, требуют, чтобы первый был именно началом диапазона, а второй - концом.

Нужно использовать что-то вроде

```
if (начало > конец)
    std::swap(начало, конец);
```

Comment: я не очень понял насчет вашего предложения во 2 :( Я думал сделать это с помощью copy и попытаться там впихнуть что-то arr[i]=arr[i]*(-1), поэтому и спрашивал можно ли впихнуть это. Но я не знаю что будет первым мин и макс, чтобы задать диапазон, тк пользователь сам потом вводит (но насчет этого думал сделать if как ваш ответ под номером 3 и туда запихнуть уже цикл по смене знака

Comment: @RedRose Я подумал, речь про другую часть задания. Тогда здесь вместо `copy` подойдет `std::foreach`, либо простой цикл. *"не знаю что будет первым мин и макс"* Не понял, при чем здесь минимум? У вас ведь диапазон от первого до последнего максимума.

Comment: я нашел похожее задание и там это трактовалось как минимум - последний максимум. Не имею понятия что конкретно имелось в виду тут, поэтому остановился на минимуме. Но если подскажете, то буду безмерно благодарен!

Comment: @RedRose Вот массив: `1 2 5 4 3 5 1 2 5 4`. В нем максимум - `5`. Первый раз он встречается на 3 позиции, последний раз - на 9. Между этими двумя позициями будет диапазон `4 3 5 1 2`.

Comment: а если не встречается? как его тогда записать в foreach? Не поймет же, наверно, если (max, max, v[i]*(-1))

Comment: @RedRose Не понял вопрос. Ищите последнее вхождение максимума через `std::find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), максимум)`, и передавайте в `std::foreach` итератор на первое вхождение (из `max_element`, плюс один) и на последнее (из `find`). А если `find` вернул то же, что и `max_element`, то вообще не вызывайте `foreach`.

Comment: auto max = *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
vector<int>::const_iterator it; 
it = v.find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), max);
foreach(max,it, v[i]*(-1)). Так нельзя?

Comment: @RedRose В комментах слишком долго объяснять, идите лучше мануалы читайте. Первый параметр foreach - итератор, а не число. Плюс, `v.find(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), ...)` возвращает `std::reverse_iterator<...>`, который еще нужно преобразовать обратно в "нормальный" итератор.